# Question about German definite articles

Tags: definite-article

> **Das** war ein Befehl!
>
> **Der** Angriff Steiners war ein Befehl!

Those are the lines heard in the movie "Der Untergang." I am not sure why *das* is used in the first sentence. What I think is if the first sentence is intended to refer to *Angriff*, then the definite article *das* should be replaced by *der* since *Angriff* is a masculine noun.

Comment: It's exactly the same as in English. "*That* was an order" vs. "*The* attack of Steiner's was an order". Pronoun vs. article.

Comment: »Das« in this case is not an article. Is is an demonstrative pronoun. If it was an article, you coult translate it to "the" in english. But "**The** was an order" is wrong. Correct is "**This** was an order".

Answer (score 7):

*Das* is used as a definite article, as you mentioned in your question. But, by itself *das* also has the meaning of *that* or *this.*

> **Das** war ein Befehl

Here, *das* stands by itself. So, it can be understood that it takes the meaning of *that* or *this*. With this, the sentence means “That was an order”.

> **Der** Angriff Steiners war ein Befehl!

Here, clearly *der* is acting as a definite article for the following noun.

Answer (score 2):

It simply means "this/that" as in:

> That was an order!

Answer (score 1):

*Das* refers to a word used before. It is an indefinite pronoun. You can find [information about that](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinitpronomen) on the German Wikipedia where this is written:

> Darüber hinaus können Indefinitpronomen substantivisch gebraucht werden, wobei sie auch dann zumeist kleingeschrieben werden:
>       Das gefiel nicht jedem. (substantivischer Gebrauch).
>       Das ist etwas anderes.

Translated to English:

> Indefinite pronouns can also be used substantivial, whereby they will be written lowercase:
>       Das gefiel nicht jedem. (substantivial use)
>       Das ist etwas anderes.

You can recognize them by trying to replace *das* with *jenes*.

*Der* is the article for the grammatical gender masculine and belongs to *Angriff*.

Comment: In the examples you cite from wikipedia, the indefinite pronouns are `jeder` and `anderes`, not `das`.

Answer (score 1):

This `das` is a [demonstrative pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonstrative#Demonstrative_determiners_and_pronouns) which stands for the referred noun (group), in this case `der Angriff Steiners`.

So yes, you can replace the `das` by this very noun group. But no, you don't have to.

If your question refers to as to why `das` is used instead of `der`: the demonstrative pronoun `das` may generically refer to events, happenings or processes, in this case the utterance of the Steiner's order.

Answer (score 0):

Das war ein Befehl! (That (what just happened) was an order)

If you amend the sentence with a noun you get:

> Das (Geschehene, Gesagte) war ein Befehl.

If you replace the nouns with.

> Die (Frau, die eben vorbeiging) war eine Asiatin.

Then the das changes to die.